# DLL load error when trying to import opensim in the spyder IDE

Tags: python, dll, spyder, anaconda3

I'm following this [tutorial](https://simtk-confluence.stanford.edu:8443/display/OpenSim/Scripting+in+Python) specifically **Installing Anaconda and the "opensim" Python package**, all the steps worked out perfectly for the last step were I'm asked to type import opensim in Spyder and I'm getting this error. what can I do to resolve it ?

- tried reinstalling Anaconda3 and opensim 4.4, but the problem persists.
- made sure my PATH includes opensim4.4\bin

import opensim
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:\Users\obaid\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_17468\2888301570.py", line 1, in <module>
    import opensim

  File "C:\Users\obaid\anaconda3\lib\opensim\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .simbody import *

  File "C:\Users\obaid\anaconda3\lib\opensim\simbody.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import _simbody

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _simbody: The specified module could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install using

> conda install -c kidzik opensim